# Error Code 1608 during SQL Server install?

Tags: windows, installation, troubleshooting, windows-registry, sql-server-2008-r2

I get the following error early during my SQL Server 2008 R2 installation:

> MsiGetProductInfo failed to retrieve ProductVersion for package with
>   Product Code = '{AEB9948B-4FF2-47C9-990E-47014492A0FE}'. Error code:
>   1608.

How can I proceed with my installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Get the Product Code = '{AEB9948B-4FF2-47C9-990E-47014492A0FE}'
2. Reverse the first segment of the GUID. For example: B8499BEA
3. Search under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\UpgradeCodes and find a matching **Value**
4. Export the parent key (optional, but remember what happened the last time you didn't?)
5. Delete the exported key

Repeat installation and repeat steps above if it complains about a different GUID.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/66a2044c-7251-466b-9b22-40d155ed949b)